# Distributing database updates to an iPhone application without downloading the whole database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a product database which I want to distribute to an iphone user application.  Its data is stored in an SqlLite database.

What i want to ask is: If i update one products' price in the database, what is the best approach to update the users copy of the database in the iphone application ? I don't want to send the whole database time to iphone users.

If i send only updated products every db will be different on each iphone after some time.
I am pretty confused.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks for your help

Comment: some clarification needed.  Have you written an iPhone application?  is it distributed with a built-in data set with prices in it?  are you asking how to update that data without redistributing the app?  How does SqlLite db fit into this?  are you using it in your app, or is this a stand-alone application by you or a third party called SqlLite db?

Comment: I'm developing app now. On Sqlite DB there are informations like products weight, height, imageurl. That kind of stuff. I'm not sure how to use sqlite. I'm looking for different kind of approaches. I'm not pretty sure how i will use sqlite.

Comment: You mentioned 2500 products.  Seems like you may as well just download the whole thing unless you have some large data associated per product.  Say with 1 KB per product, that's still only 2.5 MB, less with gzip compression -- perfectly reasonable for a once-a-week download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a global revision Id for your database. Each item in your database would additionally include a field which keeps track of the revision they were last updated at. This is much like the way subversion works.

Whenever you update one or more fields in your central database you will increment the global revision number as well as the revision number for each of the updated entries.
Your iPhone database copy would then have to keep track of its own revision. Whenever it connects to the main database it can then ask for changes made since its own revision.

Eg. if the main database is at revision 1234 and the iPhone is at revision 1222, it would. Then receive the updates corresponding to 1223, 1224, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iPhone is designed to connect to the internet, why don't you get the iPhone user application to download an updated price list from the internet (your website) each time it opens, or every week, or similar?

**update:**

If your database is large, you could track updates to your database with a version number, and create 'patches' to your database in the form of SQL statements, to move from one version of the database to the next.

When the user application connects to your website, it can look for the appropriate patches to update to the current version, and download them.

This should reduce the amount of data downloaded to the minimum, especially if you compress the patches (using zip).

Comment: There are more than 2500 products. so i don't want to load whole products range everytime.

Comment: aha, now I see what you are doing.